# Multiple conditions in WHILE loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I want to exit the while loop when the user enters 'N' or 'n'. But it does not work. It works well with one condition but not two.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Realtor {

    public static void main (String args[]){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        char myChar = 'i';

        while(myChar != 'n' || myChar != 'N'){

           System.out.println("Do you want see houses today?");
           String input = sc.next();
           myChar = input.charAt(0); 
           System.out.println("You entered "+myChar);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to change `||` to `&&` so that both conditions must be true to enter the loop.

```
while(myChar != 'n' && myChar != 'N')
```

Comment: You should also change it to a do-while loop so that you don't have to randomly initialize myChar.

Comment: Yeah, should definitely be a do-while

Comment: You can also do Character.toLowerCase(myChar) != 'n' to make it more readable.

Comment: this solved my problem. 

However, && means 'and'. This would mean both conditions have to be true. I am a PL-SQL developer and I find it difficult to understand this concept.

Comment: @user547453 If you use `||` then just one *or* the other condition can be true to enter the loop. If myChar = 'n' then `myChar != 'n'` is false, but `myChar != 'N'` is true, so it enters the loop. With `&&` since the first condition would be false, it would not enter the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is wrong.  `myChar != 'n' || myChar != 'N'` will always be true.

Use  `myChar != 'n' && myChar != 'N'` instead

Answer (score 0):

If your code, if the user enters 'X' (for instance), when you reach the while condition evaluation it will determine that 'X' is differente from 'n' (nChar != 'n') which will make your loop condition true and execute the code inside of your loop. The second condition is not even evaluated.